# Cannot Connect to MS Access 2010 64 bit Using Java 64 bit

Tags: java

I am using Eclipse 64 bit to develop a solution which connects to Ms Access 2010 64 bit.

When I am running this project using eclipse this connection works perfectly. (Does Connects to the database and does inserts, updates and deletes). However when I export it out as a executable *.jar file and run it it will give me this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Why does it work in eclipse and do not work as a jar file??

Also if I copy this jar file in to 32 bit computer and execute this jar file with `jre-7u6-windows-i586` java runtime it will work perfectly.

Does anybody know a reason why it works in 32bit computer and not in 64 bit Computers??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What the error is telling you is that you're missing the Database Driver class (ODBC Driver Manager) in your JAR. Copy the jar that has that file into your /lib folder in eclipse project, and then recompile your jar for export such that it includes the /lib of the project.

Comment: Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + fileName;        
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "test", "sa");This is my connection string which jar file do you want me to add please help

Comment: I didn't think you used internal sun's JDBC driver, I thought you used a JDBC driver from an external jar (well at least I do that). My thought on what is happening here is that, the JDK in Eclipse has the sun.* classes so it can run your application, but the JRE on your OS does not have that specific JDBC class in its sun.* package, so it cannot run it. Could you try downloading a JDBC driver for Access as a separate jar from an external link, then adding that jar under your project's /lib, loading that class instead of sun's, and then exporting your project into an executable jar?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.math.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
```

/* database connectivity with MS-Access is done by creating
DataSourceName(dsn) in this example*/
   /* Steps to use this example:

- go to ms-access and make a table called "student_base" and give it a
  file name student_base.mdb
- 1. Go to Control Panel
  2. Click  on Administrative Tools(windows 2000/xp), Click on
     ODBC(win98)
  3. click on ODBC
  4. Then , you will see a ODBC dialog box. Click on UserDSn
  5. Click on Add Button
  6. Select Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb) driver and click on finish
  7. Give a Data Source Name : student_base
  8. Then Click on Select
  9. Browse on the database name you have created and click
     it:student_base.mdb is a database file where all data
     will be stored
  10. Click on OK.
      Once the DSN is created, you can do this example*/

      public class AddNewStudent extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

      private JButton btnok,btnexit,btnaddnew; //buttons
        private JTextField tf1,tf2;//textfields
        private JLabel lblname,lbladd,lblmsg; //labels

      private JPanel p1,p2,p3,psouth; //panels

      public AddNewStudent() //constructor
        {
      //initializing buttons
      btnok = new JButton("OK");
      btnok.addActionListener(this);
      btnexit = new JButton("Exit");
      btnexit.addActionListener(this);
      btnaddnew = new JButton("AddNew");
      btnaddnew.addActionListener(this);

  //initializing textfields
  tf1 = new JTextField(12);
  tf2 = new JTextField(12);
  //initializing labels

lblname = new JLabel("Name:");
lbladd = new JLabel("Address:");
lblmsg = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);

```
//initializing panels
```

p1 = new JPanel();
p2 = new JPanel();
p3 = new JPanel();
psouth = new JPanel();

```
//adding buttons and label to panel p1
//setting flowlayout
```

p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

p1.add(btnok);
p1.add(btnexit);
p1.add(btnaddnew);
    //adding lblmsg to panel p3
p3.add(lblmsg);

```
//adding both the panels to new panel,psouth
//settin layout 2:1


   psouth.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    psouth.add(p3);
    psouth.add(p1);


//adding label and textfields to panel p2
```

p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
//setting line and titled border for panel p2
p2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
p2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Enter Your Details"));
p2.add(lblname);
p2.add(tf1);
p2.add(lbladd);
p2.add(tf2);

```
//adding panel to container
    this.getContentPane().add(p2,"Center");
    this.getContentPane().add(psouth,"South");

    this.setSize(300,300);
    this.setLocation(100,200);
    this.show();


   }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      AddNewStudent ad = new AddNewStudent();
    }
```

//event handling

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
   if(e.getSource()==btnok)
   {
      PreparedStatement pstm;
      ResultSet rs;
      String sql;
  //if no entries has been made and hit ok button throw an error
  //you can do this step using try clause as well
```

if((tf1.getText().equals("")&&(tf2.getText().equals(""))))
  {
    lblmsg.setText("Enter your details ");
    lblmsg.setForeground(Color.magenta);
  }

else
{

try
 {
       //loading the driver
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

```
    //connection object created using DriverManager class
    //student_base is the name of the database
        Connection connect =
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:student_base");

    //creating prepared statement object pstm so that query can be
```

sent to database

```
        pstm=connect.prepareStatement("insert into student_base
values(?,?)");
        pstm.setString(1,tf1.getText());
        pstm.setString(2,tf2.getText());
        //execute method to execute the query
        pstm.executeUpdate();
        lblmsg.setText("Details have been added to database");



     //closing the prepared statement  and connection object


pstm.close();
 connect.close();
```

}
   catch(SQLException sqe)
   {
     System.out.println("SQl error");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnf)
    {
     System.out.println("Class not found error");
    }
   }
 }
    //upon clickin button addnew , your textfield will be empty to 
enter

```
next record
    if(e.getSource()==btnaddnew)
    {
      tf1.setText("");
      tf2.setText("");
    }

    if(e.getSource()==btnexit)
    {
      System.exit(1);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: How does this explain why it doesn't work on 64-bit machines?

Comment: have checked it in a 32 bit machine?